# How do I optimize my stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, stored-procedures

I ran a profiler today and found that one of my stored procedures is taking a very high CPU read (1899999) and duration (3233333).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could start by showing us the contents of your stored procedure...Otherwise a generic answer like "Check to see what operations are being performed and optimise accordingly" will have to do.